# Blocking statement in thread results in longer time to kill thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I start a custom thread in Python which is supposed to regularly print some statistical information about the current progress. As soon as the user signifies to stop the program, all threads must be killed. This works so far, but for the stated thread.

```
def print_statistics(thread_id):
    print "Thread {} started (information thread)".format(thread_id)

    # thread_stop_event is of type threading.Event
    while (not thread_stop_event.is_set()):

        print "important information"
        time.sleep(5) # print some information every five seconds


    print "Thread {} is terminating - Bye".format(thread_id)
```

I use a threading.Event that is unset once the user indicates to quit the program. Then the daemon process finishes and the thread stops automatically.

I am aware of time.sleep(). As it only blocks five seconds, the thread should be killed in the worst case after this time has elapsed.

Now I did the following observation: As longer the user waits for his command to kill all threads, the longer it takes to kill `print_statistics`. Why? Shouldn't it take up to a maximum of five seconds?

**EDIT**

This is the main method that handles all threads. At first worker threads are started and eventuell the information thread which provides the user with current statistical information.

```
def run():
    running_threads = list()

    # start working threads
    for i in range(0, max_threads):
        t = Thread(target=worker_thread, args=(i,))
        running_threads.append(t)
        running_threads[i].start()

    # start thread that provides user with statistical information
    inf_thread = Thread(target=print_statistics, args=(max_threads,))
    inf_thread.start()

    # wait for user interrupt
    while True:
        input = raw_input("\nType \"quit\" to quit!\n")
        if input == "quit":
            thread_stop_event.set() # inform all threads to terminate
            break
        else:
            print "Input not recognized. Try again!"
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem? The main thread that sets the event is missing.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but have you tried using asynchronous IO instead of spawning new threads ? Too many times I was using threading just for it's non-blocking effect and not for the cpu scaling.  I've switched to [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) (there're other options) a while ago and now I don't need to bother with threads going rogue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is, but you should be using

```
while not thread_stop_event.wait(5):
    print "important information"
```